# application appear before lock screen

Tags: android, ios, background, lockscreen

just signed up to ask a question for my idea to see if anybody knows it's technically possible to do so.

To clarify, I'm thinking about developing an application for Android or iOS; application opens and I tap a big button, which will close / hide the application and work in the background, the tricky part is:

When it's working in the background, is it possible that when I open my phones screen, this applications screen appear on top of the lock screen, so that the lock screen is (at least partially) hidden by it?

Comment: You can't do this on iOS.

Comment: You can do it in `Android` by customizing AOSP. So `Android` beats ios )

Comment: Thank you both for your quick replies. I've searched AOSP and it looked too alien for me (still got much to learn even for basics). 

I changed my mind to make it appear after lock screen so that should be more simple and easy (I presume).